# The square does not move JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I'm creating a game, the div with id "playerDiv" when I hit the space bar it should start going up but it doesn't. So I would like when I hit the space bar the div would go up high.
could you help me? could you also report me the mistakes i made?

```js
const player = document.getElementById("playerDiv");
let inc = 0;
let playerTimeOut;

function jump() {
  let x = 420 + inc;
  player.top = player.top + x;
  inc++
  playerTimeOut = setTimeout(jump, 50);
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);

function checkKeyPress(key) {
  if (key.key === ' ') {
    jump();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

#background {
  border: solid 2px #dddddd;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

#playerDiv {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 420px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="background">
    <div id="playerDiv">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated. Use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Comment: As suggested above change the check to `if (key.key === ' ')`

Comment: Also styles can be changed with `player.style.top = x + 'px';`

Comment: use transform translate actually it's good for animation and doesn't repaint everything around it or use position: absolute

Comment: @Ale did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the argument in addListener and you're not using correctly the top property, it belongs to `style` and needs unit , for example `px`

Also `keyCode` is deprecated, use `key` instead

```js
const player = document.getElementById("playerDiv");
let inc = 0;
let playerTimeOut;

function jump() {
  let x = 10 + inc;
  player.style.bottom = `${x}px`
  inc++
  console.log(player.style.bottom)
}

//window.addEventListener("keydown", e =>  e.key === "(Space Character)" ? jump() : '');

//For snippet only
jump()

setTimeout(() => jump(), 1000)
```

```css
* {
  /* demo */
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
}

#background {
  border: solid 2px #ddd;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  /* demo */
  max-width: 100%
}

#playerDiv {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="playerDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem is that even though the player.top increments, the square doesn't move up

Comment: @Vitalii thanks you made me understand the error now it works with this string of code: `let x = 420 - inc;` and `player.style.top = x +" px ";`

Comment: @Ale I improved a bit your code, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const player = document.getElementById("playerDiv");
let inc = 0;
let playerTimeOut;

function jump() {
  let x = 10 + inc;
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(player);
  player.style.top = (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('top'),10) - x) + 'px';
  inc++
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);

function checkKeyPress(key) {
  if (key.keyCode == "32") {
    jump();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

#background {
  border: solid 2px #dddddd;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

#playerDiv {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 420px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="playerDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```